# AlarmManager срабатывет только один раз

Tags: android

AlarmManager срабатывает только один раз после его назначения.

**Код:**

```
    private void setAlarm() {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TimeNotification.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, dbHelper.getAlarmTime(DBHelper.ALARM_HOURS));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dbHelper.getAlarmTime(DBHelper.ALARM_MINUTES));

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. и дальше читайте https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: @Style-7, там написано, что не гарантируется точность срабатывания, но это не значит что он не будет работать вообще.

Comment: в моём случае он вообще не работает. SDK 28, тестирую на xiaomi Note 7

Comment: На сяо-мяо у вас должен быть блокировщик фоновых процессов, который по дефолту блокирует всех, и нужно ручками добавить ваше приложение ему в белый список.

Comment: @woesss я знаю, что там написано и вижу задачу которую он решает. Если вам не составит труда, то не нужно комментировать меня - общайтесь с автором вопроса,